# Calling reset on Media Player after calling setDataSource, Freezes UI

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Im working on a Music Player app, and all the music handled by the app are from streaming resources.

Everytime the user changes songs, i need to call reset and set a new dataSource. If the user rapidly switches songs, and the MediaPlayer is on the preparing state, the UI from my app freezes.

This only happens if i call reset and the media player is in the preparing state.

How can i prevent my app UI from freezing and getting an ANR?

PS: Im using prepareAsync(), not prepare().

Answer (score 0):

See setOnPreparedListener. You can keep track of the state in your class through various listeners and avoid calling prepareAsync().

You might have better luck also calling stop() before reset().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29